# How to debug file change notifications obtained by FindFirstChangeNotification?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, notifications

So, the question is: I get some notifications I don't want to get. But I don't know for what file/dir I got them. Is there a way to know why given notification was fired?

If you think about ReadDirectoryChangesW, please include a meaningful code sample.

Comment: What's so hard about using ReadDirectoryChangesW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like Windows to tell you what specific file or subdirectory changed, you will need to use [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx). The asynchronous mode is fairly simple if you use a completion routine.

On the other hand, you will probably get better performance by using the slightly more complicated [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx) approach. I would recommend downloading Wes Jones' excellent [CDirectoryChangeWatcher](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx)  source code as a starting point. There are several gotchas that his code will help you avoid, particularly in parsing the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` records.

Answer (score 0):

~pseudocode

```
HANDLE handles[MAX_HANDLES];
std::string dir_array[MAX_HANDLES];

for i from 0 to MAX_HANDLES:
   h[i] = FindFirstChangeNotification(dir_array[i]...);

nCount = MAX_HANDLES;
ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(handles, nCount ...);

// check if ret returns something between WAIT_OBJECT_0 and WAIT_OBJECT_0+nCount-1
if "so":
  ret -= WAIT_OBJECT_0;
  cout << "Directory " << dir_array[ret] << " changed" << endl;
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

See on professional Win32 api newsgroup news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
for well-known MS samples (C code) (since 90's...)